# C++ Rvalue references and move semantics

Tags: c#, java, c++, c++11

C++03 had the problem of unnecessary copies that could happen implicitly. For this purpose, C++11 introduced `rvalue references` and `move semantics`. Now my question is, do this unnecessary copying problem also exist in languages such as C# and java or was it only a C++ problem? In other words, does `rvalue references` make C++11 even more efficient as compared to C# or Java?

As far as C# concerned (operator overloading allowed in it), lets say we have a mathematical vector class, and we use it like this.

```
vector_a = vector_b + vector_c;
```

The compiler will surely transform `vector_b + vector_c` to some temporary object (lets call it `vector_tmp`).

Now I don't think C# can differentiate between a temporary rvalue such as `vector_tmp` or a an lvalue such as `vector_b`, so we'll have to copy data to `vector_a` anyway, which can easily be avoided by using `rvalue references` and `move semantics` in C++11.

Comment: don't use language tags that are unrelated

Answer (score 7):

Class references in C# and Java have some properties of `shared_ptr`s in C++. However, rvalue references and move semantics relate more to temporary value types, but the value types in C# are quite non-flexible compared to C++ value types, and from my own C# experience, you'll end up with classes, not structs, most of the time.

So my assumption is that neither Java nor C# would profit much from those new C++ features, which lets code make safe assumptions whether something is a temporary, and instead of copying lets it just steal the content.

Answer (score 5):

yes unnecessary copy operation  are there in C# and java.

does rvalue references make C++11 even more efficient as compared to C# or Java?

answer is yes. :)

Comment: When do you mean that it occurs in Java? Please provide an example. It can occur in specific implementations calling clone etc., but that seems to be beside the point. Java doesn't have default copy constructors and implicit copies since it passed references to objects by default (actually by value).

Comment: Sebastian Olsson: Apparently rvalue references have nothing to do with copy constructors. It has to do with temperory rvalues. How does C# handle that? I mean how does it handle copying from temporary objects. For example you have a class with overloaded operations and you have this expression a = b + c + d. How does C++ and C# handle it differently. Assume C++ implementation use references.

Comment: It is about an unnecessary destruct-construct. My point was that Java does not infer object creation the way C++ does. I dare not answer about operator overloading in C# since it is not my area of expertise.

Comment: Sebastian: I see what you mean. You are saying that since Java does not have copy constructors, this problem does not exist in Java.

Comment: Well. Almost. I'm saying that since Java doesn't pass by value with automatic object copy using copy constructors but rather by value as in reference to the object it does not happen. If java automatically called a deep clone() when passing an object it would be the same problem. Part of the problem could occur in specific implementations in Java if you for example simulate operator overloading with immutable methods such as a = a.add(b.add(c)) if add creates a new object, but there is no such default behavior in Java.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, it was really helpful. Perhaps you can write this as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Because classes in Java and C# use reference semantics, there are never any implicit copies of objects in those languages. The problem move semantics solve does not and has never existed in Java and C#.

Comment: C++ can also use reference semantics. Infact, copy constructors are almost always written such that they take constant references. So the problem doesn't seem to do anything with references.

Comment: "Passing by reference" and "reference semantics" are two different things.

Comment: In C#, structs have value semantics and classes have reference semantics. Also in C#, if you want to pass by reference, you use the `ref` qualifier. Without the `ref` qualifier, you get call by value. Both concepts are completely orthogonal: You can pass struct types by value or by reference, and you can pass class types by value or by reference.

Comment: FredOverflow. I already know that C# passes copies of object references. And you can use ref or out to pass reference of reference.

Comment: FredOverflow - Say if you have operator overloading based Mathematical vector class and you use it like this in C#, "vector_a = vector_b + vector_c". How will C# achieve that without copying? The compiler will surely tranlsate vector_b + vector_c to some temperory (lets call it vector_tmp) and then assign it to vector_a, right? So ya, there will be some copying involved there? What C++11 do here is that through rvalue references, it allows the compiler to access vector_tmp as a reference, which is impossible in C++03, due to the fact that rvalues cannot be referenced in it.

Comment: @MetallicPriest Yes and the whole "copying" that will happen in both Java and C# in that situation (assuming a class in c#) is the assignment of a reference to `vector_a` (which you need anyhow in c++ as well). In your given example there will never be more than 3 objects involved (and possibly less if `vector_b` and `vector_c` are the same object or `+` returns an existing object). rvals are a solution for a c++ problem that doesn't even exist in other languages to begin with..

Comment: @Voo, I totally disagree with you. I think you didn't understand the purpose of rvalues and move semantics. C# has no way to know if an object is a temporary rvalue or an lvalue. So, for example if you have vector_a = vector_b, there you do need to copy vector_b data to vector_a, but for expression, vector_a = vector_b + vector_c, you know that vector_tmp (=vector_b + vector_c) is a temporary rvalue, whose pointer to data can just be forwarded to vector_a, therefore no copying is required in C++11. C# can't differentiate the two and therefore you would need to copy data in both cases.

Comment: @MetallicPriest Sadly I do understand rvals, not much around with the new standard. b2t: `vector_b + vector_c` is syntactic sugar for something like `vector add(vector x, vector y)`. In the simplest case we create a new object and return a reference to it. You can think of this returned reference to the object as your `vector_tmp`. The only thing that happens afterwards is that we assign the **reference** to a local variable. There's no concept of copy constructors or assignment operators in Java or C# (at least not for the compiler).

Comment: Basically it boils down to the fact that as its heart C++ is a value passing language (mostly because that makes the whole concept of who owns what object and who is responsible for the memory pretty simple), but sadly that has some rather large overhead - rvals remedy that to some degree. Both Java and C# take the opposite approach, so there's nothing to be gained from having rvals. The largest thing that can be passed around in Java (and c# ignoring structs) is 8byte in size (a pointer to an object)

Comment: @Voo - Ah I see, I didn't know that C# doesn't allow overloading an assignment operator. Perhaps they avoided it just for this reason.

Comment: @Voo - But wait a minute. What would C# behave for an expression like this, va + vb + vc + vd. Like you said it will create a new object on each addition, which can be avoided by using C+11 move semantics. I mean the same temporary object can be used for addition again and again,  Like vt = vc + vd, then vt += vb and finally va += vt. While in C# you would have something like this, vt1 = vc + vd, vt2 = vt1 + vb and then va += vt2.

Comment: @Metallic I wouldn't be using operators there (because of completely different semantics in all 3 involved languages), but instead functions. And then yes, you can make a function that returns a new object in C# - but you can just as well make a function that mutates a given object (which is what `+=` in C++ does).

Answer (score 1):

I think it could occur in Java. See the add and add_to operation below. add creates a result object to hold the result of the matrix add operation, while add_to merely adds the rhs to this.

```
class Matrix   {
   public static final int w = 2;
   public static final int h = 2;

   public float [] data;

   Matrix(float v)
   {
       data = new float[w*h];
       for(int i=0; i<w*h; ++i)
           { data[i] = v; }
   }

   // Creates a new Matrix by adding this and rhs 
   public Matrix add(Matrix rhs)
   {
       Main result = new Main(0.0f);
       for(int i=0; i<w*h; ++i)
           { result.data[i] = this.data[i] + rhs.data[i]; }

       return result;
   }

   // Just adds the values in rhs to this
   public Main add_to(Main rhs)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<w*h; ++i)
           { this.data[i] += rhs.data[i]; }
       return this;    
   }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       Matrix m = new Matrix(0.0f);
       Matrix n = new Matrix(1.0f);
       Matrix o = new Matrix(1.0f);

       // Chaining these ops would modify m
       // Matrix result = m.add_to(n).subtract_from(o);      
       m.add_to(n);         // Adds n to m
       m.subtract_from(o);  // Subtract o from n

       // Can chain ops without modifying m,
       // but temps created to hold results from each step
       Matrix result = m.add(n).subtract(o);
    }
}
```

Thus, I think it depends on what sort of functionality you're providing to the user with your classes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes up a lot.  Someone I want to hold onto a unique copy of an object that no one else can modify.  How do I do that?

1. Make a deep copy of whatever object someone gives me?  That would work, but it's not efficient.
2. Ask people to give me a new object and not to keep a copy?  That's faster if you're brave.  Bugs can come from a completely unrelated piece of code modifying the object hours later.
3. C++ style:  Move all the items from the input to my own new object.  If the caller accidentally tries to use the object again, he will immediately see the problem.
4. Sometimes a C# read only collection can help.  But in my experiences that's usually a pain at best.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
class LongLivedObject
{
    private Dictionary <string, string> _settings;
    public LongLivedObject(Dictionary <string, string> settings)
    {   // In C# this always duplicates the data structure and takes O(n) time.
        // C++ will automatically try to decide if it could do a swap instead.
        // C++ always lets you explicitly say you want to do the swap.
        _settings = new Dictionary <string, string>(settings);
    }
}
```

This question is at the heart of Clojure and other functional languages!

In summary, yes, I often wish I had C++11 style data structures and operations in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to emulate move semantics. For instance in Trade-Ideas Philip's example you can pass custom `MovableDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`:

```
public class MovableDictionary<K, V> // : IDictionary<K, V>, IReadOnlyDictionary<K, V>...
{
    private Dictionary<K, V> _map;

    // Implement all Dictionary<T>'s methods by calling Map's ones.

    public Dictionary<K, V> Move()
    {
        var result = Map;
        _map = null;
        return result;
    }

    private Dictionary<K, V> Map
    {
        get
        {
            if (_map == null)
                _map = new Dictionary<K, V>();

            return _map;
        }
    }
}
```