# Does Java have an ArrayList.take() equivilent

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a case where I need to remove a block from one ArrayList and create a new ArrayList with that block. The code does this a lot and so it's a big memory & performance issue at present.

Is there any way ([I'm guessing no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022441/how-to-move-contents-of-one-arraylist-to-another)) where I can take a block from an ArrayList and it gives it to me as a new ArrayList?

Code example:

```
destTable.rowTable.addAll(srcTable.rowTable.subList(startIndex, endIndex));
srcTable.rowTable.removeRange(startIndex, endIndex);
```

The thing is, for one example startIndex = 45 and endIndex = 74958 so the above is a big hit in terms of time and memory. And the endIndex is the end of the data in the source array so if this is implemented somehow, it should be fast.

Comment: Can you use [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-)?

Comment: Do note that if you use subList to get a view as @bcsb1001 suggested, it will copy references into a new array so any change to the "new" array will result in original array as well.

Comment: If you provide a bit more details we may be able to offer you more help, like does new ArrayList have to be completely independent from the one whose elements you will be copying, what elements are you planning to copy, is it a continuous range of elements like from let's say index 5 to index 12 or is there a check performed on every element and if element satisfies that check it gets copied or is there something else ?

Comment: @user2357112 - I'm 99% certain that that does answer my question (not the answer I wanted).

Comment: Do you need random access? Or can it be a LinkedList?

Comment: The title asks about `take()` method. In my limited experience, `take` usually means taking a number of elements from the beginning or end of the list. `slice` would be a better term for the title in my opinion. That said, I think a good way is to use `Iterator.remove()` (while being careful not to mess up the collection).

Comment: @cricket_007 - A linked list would be an even bigger hit memory wise. And probably performance wise.

Comment: @jrook I used take() because that's what it's called in C#. You're right that slice() is the equivilent in javascript and would also be valid.

Comment: Storing nodes and pointers is less performant than an array/list?

Comment: @cricket_007 Everytime I've measured both for code we had ArrayList tended to be 2X or better performance wise. And it's always less of a memory footprint.

Comment: My main point is that if you're chopping apart a list and only iterating it from a starting position, LinkedList might be preferred.

Comment: @cricket_007 - Yes, there are times that would work. But in this case we go through what is stored in the lists a lot. So ArrayLists are better even with this issue. What I'm doing is flipping it - pulling the short block out of the large block and then assigning each list to the other table.